# get start date of week from week number and year only

Tags: datetime, time, sas, week-number

I have a dataset where the data is reported by week and year like: YYWW. I have split it into to columns: Year and Week.

I need to get a date from the week: Week_start_date. My weeks start at mondays, so I would like to get the monday and sunday date from each week.

| ID | YYWW | year | week | Week_start_date | Week_end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1504 | 2015 | 04 | ? | ? |
| 2 | 1651 | 2016 | 51 | ? | ? |
| 3 | 1251 | 2012 | 51 | ? | ? |
| 4 | 1447 | 2014 | 47 | ? | ? |

How do I extract the week start date from just a week number and year?
I've looked at several threads at SO, but haven't found a solution yet.

I have tried looking at different threads, but encounters problems using their solutions. Most seaches for "convert week number and year to date" on google and SO returns the opposite: Getting a weeknumber from a date. This guy answered by Vince, have maybe some similar issues, but I can't get the code to do the job: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Converting-week-number-to-start-date/td-p/106456

Answer (score 1):

Use INTNX() with the WEEK interval and increment from the first of the year.
Use +1 to get Monday/Sunday dates.

You may need to tweak to match the dates you need.

```
data have;
infile cards dlm='09'x;
input ID $  YYWW    year    week ;
format year 8. week z2.;
cards;  
1   1504    2015    04  
2   1651    2016    51  
3   1251    2012    51  
4   1447    2014    47
;;;;

data want;
set have;
    week_start = intnx('week', mdy(1, 1, year), week, 'b')+1;
    week_end = intnx('week', mdy(1, 1, year), week, 'e')+1;
    format week_: date9.;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Reeza!!! 
It helped me with my problem. 
I didn't really understand what you wrote in the following:

data have;
infile cards dlm='09'x;
input ID $  YYWW    year    week ;
format year 8. week z2.;
cards; 

Can you find time to elaborate so I'm not staying n00b  :)

Comment: That step just creates the sample data you had typed out to test the program works and have input data. You would use your actual data instead.

Comment: @Reeza Your data step to create the sample data will not work when run from normal SAS editor since TABS in code are converted to spaces when the code is submitted to be run.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the WEEK... informats.  But you will need to insert the letter W between the YEAR and WEEK number.

```
data have;
  input ID $  YYWW    year    week ;
cards;  
1 1504 2015 04
2 1651 2016 51
3 1251 2012 51
4 1447 2014 47
;;;;

data want;
  set have;
  week_start=input(cats(year,'W',put(week,Z2.)),weekv.);
  week_end=week_start+6;
  format week_: yymmdd10.;
run;

Results

Obs    ID    YYWW    year    week    week_start      week_end

 1     1     1504    2015      4     2015-01-19    2015-01-25
 2     2     1651    2016     51     2016-12-19    2016-12-25
 3     3     1251    2012     51     2012-12-17    2012-12-23
 4     4     1447    2014     47     2014-11-17    2014-11-23
```